# Computing $\bmod$s with large exponents by paper and pencil using Fermat's Little Theorem.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I'm having a bit of trouble computing $\bmod{mod}$s of large numbers using Fermat's Little Theorem.

For example, how would you compute $7^{435627650}\mod 13$? The solution given is

> $435627650\mod 12=2,$ so $7^2\mod{13} = 10.$

In general, how does one solve this type of question with large exponents and mods by paper and pencil? I'm also a bit confused about where the $12$ came from and how this problem was solved.

Comment: If $(a,p)=1$,then $a^{p-1}=1 \pmod p$.

Comment: Yes, it is $10$. By Fermat's Theorem, $7^{13-1}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. Note that if we replace the $50$ at the end of the exponent by $48$, we get a number $n$ divisible by $3$ and $4$, so by $12$. So $n=12k$ for some $k$, and therefore $7^{12k}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. So with the real exponent, we get a result congruent to $7^2$.

Answer (score 6):

> **Fermat's Little Theorem:** If $p$ is prime and $a$ is an integer, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Say we're given a number $a$ and some big exponent $N$ and we want to compute $$a^N\mod p.$$   We know that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.  In general, if $a_1\equiv x_1\pmod{n}$ and $a_2\equiv x_2\pmod{n}$, then $a_1a_2\equiv x_1x_2\pmod{n}$.  Therefore, we have that 
$$a^{k(p-1)}=\underbrace{a^{p-1}\cdot a^{p-1}\cdot \cdots \cdot a^{p-1}}_{k\text{ times}}\equiv \underbrace{1\cdot 1 \cdot \cdots \cdot 1}_{k\text{ times}}\pmod p\equiv 1 \pmod p. $$
Thus we can ignore the part of $N$ which is the biggest multiple of $p-1$. Writing $N=m(p-1)+r$ where $0\leq r < p-1$, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}a^N &=& a^{m(p-1)+r}\\&=&\left(a^{p-1}\right)^ma^r\\ &\equiv& 1^ma^r\pmod p\\ &\equiv& a^r\pmod p.\end{eqnarray*}$$
Thus we have reduced this to the much easier problem of computing $a^r\mod p$.  If this is still too hard to work out with pen and paper, you might try using the method of [repeat squaring](http://www.tricki.org/article/To_work_out_powers_mod_n_use_repeated_squaring).